# Fazer uma consulta com criteria hibernate com Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, criteria

Boa noite, amigos, tenho uma dúvida.

Tenho uma Classe chamada Proposta e outra Chamada Cliente.

Na cliente existe o campo CPF e uma Proposta tem um Cliente.

Necessito fazer a busca de `proposta.cliente.cpf`, mas não estou conseguindo, poderiam me ajudar?

Model Proposta

@Entity
@Table(name = "proposta") // Vou fazer referencia ao flyway //
public class Proposta implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Relacionamento Proposta x Produto
@NotNull(message = "O produto é obrigatório")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "codigo_produto")
private Produto produto;

// Relacionamento Proposta x Banco
@NotNull(message = "O banco é obrigatório")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "codigo_banco")
private Banco banco;

@NotNull(message = "A tabela é obrigatório")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "codigo_tabela")
private Tabela tabela;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long codigo;

// Padrao de expressao
// @ADE
@NotBlank(message = "A ADE é obrigatória")
@Size(max = 50, message = "O tamanho da ADE deve estar entre 1 e 50")
@Column(unique = true)
private String ade;

@NotBlank(message = "A descrição é obrigatória")
@Size(max = 50, message = "O tamanho da  descrição deve estar entre 1 e 50")
private String descricao;

@NotNull(message = "A origem é obrigatório")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Origem origem;

@NotNull(message = "O valor Parcela é obrigatório")
@DecimalMin("0.01")
@DecimalMax(value = "9999999.99", message = "O valor da proposta deve ser menor que R$9.999.999,99")
private BigDecimal valorParcela;

@NotNull(message = "O valor Total é obrigatório")
@DecimalMin("0.01")
@DecimalMax(value = "9999999.99", message = "O valor da proposta deve ser menor que R$9.999.999,99")
private BigDecimal valorTotal;

@NotNull(message = "O valor Líquido é obrigatório")
@DecimalMin("0.01")
@DecimalMax(value = "9999999.99", message = "O valor da proposta deve ser menor que R$9.999.999,99")
private BigDecimal valorLiquido;

@Column(name = "data_proposta")
private LocalDate dataProposta;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "codigo_cliente")
private Cliente cliente;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "proposta")
private List<Comissao> comissoes;

@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
private void prePersistUpdate() {
    descricao = descricao.toUpperCase();
}

public Produto getProduto() {
    return produto;
}

public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
    this.produto = produto;
}

public Banco getBanco() {
    return banco;
}

public void setBanco(Banco banco) {
    this.banco = banco;
}

public Tabela getTabela() {
    return tabela;
}

public void setTabela(Tabela tabela) {
    this.tabela = tabela;
}

public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getAde() {
    return ade;
}

public void setAde(String ade) {
    this.ade = ade;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public Origem getOrigem() {
    return origem;
}

public void setOrigem(Origem origem) {
    this.origem = origem;
}

public BigDecimal getValorParcela() {
    return valorParcela;
}

public void setValorParcela(BigDecimal valorParcela) {
    this.valorParcela = valorParcela;
}

public BigDecimal getValorTotal() {
    return valorTotal;
}

public void setValorTotal(BigDecimal valorTotal) {
    this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
}

public BigDecimal getValorLiquido() {
    return valorLiquido;
}

public void setValorLiquido(BigDecimal valorLiquido) {
    this.valorLiquido = valorLiquido;
}

public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public List<Comissao> getComissoes() {
    return comissoes;
}

public void setComissoes(List<Comissao> comissoes) {
    this.comissoes = comissoes;
}

public LocalDate getDataProposta() {
    return dataProposta;
}

public void setDataProposta(LocalDate dataProposta) {
    this.dataProposta = dataProposta;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Proposta other = (Proposta) obj;
    if (codigo == null) {
        if (other.codigo != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public Proposta(Produto produto, Banco banco, Tabela tabela, Long codigo, String ade, String descricao,
        Origem origem, BigDecimal valorParcela, BigDecimal valorTotal, BigDecimal valorLiquido, Cliente cliente,
        List<Comissao> comissoes) {
    super();
    this.produto = produto;
    this.banco = banco;
    this.tabela = tabela;
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.ade = ade;
    this.descricao = descricao;
    this.origem = origem;
    this.valorParcela = valorParcela;
    this.valorTotal = valorTotal;
    this.valorLiquido = valorLiquido;
    this.cliente = cliente;
    this.comissoes = comissoes;
}

public Proposta() {
    super();
}
```

}

Model Cliente

@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true)
private Long codigo;

@NotBlank(message = "Nome é obrigatório")
@Size(max = 50, message = "O tamanho da  descrição deve estar entre 1 e 50")
private String nome;

@NotBlank(message = "Sobrenome obrigatório")
@Size(max = 50, message = "O tamanho da  descrição deve estar entre 1 e 50")
private String sobrenome;

@NotBlank(message = "Email é obrigatorio")
@Column(unique = true)
private String email;

@NotBlank(message = "Telefone é obrigatorio")
private String telefone;

@NotBlank(message = "CPF é obrigatório")
@Column(unique = true)
private String cpf;

@NotBlank(message = "CPF é obrigatório")
private String rg;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario")
private List<Equipe> equipes;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Genero genero;

@NotNull(message = "A conta  é obrigatório")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "codigo_conta")
private Conta conta;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cliente")
private List<Proposta> propostas;


@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
private void prePersistUpdate() {
    nome = nome.toUpperCase();
    sobrenome = sobrenome.toUpperCase();
    email   = email.toUpperCase();
}



public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getSobrenome() {
    return sobrenome;
}

public void setSobrenome(String sobrenome) {
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getRg() {
    return rg;
}

public void setRg(String rg) {
    this.rg = rg;
}

public List<Equipe> getEquipes() {
    return equipes;
}

public void setEquipes(List<Equipe> equipes) {
    this.equipes = equipes;
}

public Genero getGenero() {
    return genero;
}

public void setGenero(Genero genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}

public Conta getConta() {
    return conta;
}

public void setConta(Conta conta) {
    this.conta = conta;
}

public List<Proposta> getPropostas() {
    return propostas;
}

public void setPropostas(List<Proposta> propostas) {
    this.propostas = propostas;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
    if (codigo == null) {
        if (other.codigo != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
        return false;
    return true;
}

public Cliente(Long codigo, String nome, String sobrenome, String email, String telefone, String cpf, String rg,
        List<Equipe> equipes, Genero genero, Conta conta, List<Proposta> propostas) {
    super();
    this.codigo = codigo;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.sobrenome = sobrenome;
    this.email = email;
    this.telefone = telefone;
    this.cpf = cpf;
    this.rg = rg;
    this.equipes = equipes;
    this.genero = genero;
    this.conta = conta;
    this.propostas = propostas;
}

public Cliente() {
    super();
}
```

}

Vou postar o codigo de PropostaFilter :

```
package com.bss.sistema.genesis.repository.filter;

import java.math.BigDecimal;   
import com.bss.sistema.genesis.model.Banco;
import com.bss.sistema.genesis.model.Cliente;
import com.bss.sistema.genesis.model.Produto;
import com.bss.sistema.genesis.model.Tabela;

public class PropostaFilter {


private String ade;
private Cliente cliente;
private Banco banco;
private Produto produto;
private Tabela tabela;
private BigDecimal valorDe;
private BigDecimal valorAte;

public String getAde() {
    return ade;
}

public void setAde(String ade) {
    this.ade = ade;
}

public Cliente getCliente() {
    return cliente;
}

public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    this.cliente = cliente;
}

public Banco getBanco() {
    return banco;
}

public void setBanco(Banco banco) {
    this.banco = banco;
}

public Produto getProduto() {
    return produto;
}

public void setProduto(Produto produto) {
    this.produto = produto;
}

public Tabela getTabela() {
    return tabela;
}

public void setTabela(Tabela tabela) {
    this.tabela = tabela;
}

public BigDecimal getValorDe() {
    return valorDe;
}

public void setValorDe(BigDecimal valorDe) {
    this.valorDe = valorDe;
}

public BigDecimal getValorAte() {
    return valorAte;
}

public void setValorAte(BigDecimal valorAte) {
    this.valorAte = valorAte;
}
```

}

#

PropostaImpl:

```
package com.bss.sistema.genesis.repository.helper.proposta;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import com.bss.sistema.genesis.model.Proposta;
import com.bss.sistema.genesis.repository.filter.PropostaFilter;

public class PropostasImpl implements PropostasQueries {


@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager manager;
// Criando a Criteria para Usuario = filtro
// Pra pegar a criteria do Hibernate precisa de uma transacao , apenas de
// leitura

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Proposta> filtrar(PropostaFilter filtro) {
    Criteria criteria = manager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Proposta.class);
    if (filtro != null) {

        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(filtro.getAde())) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ade", filtro.getAde()));
        }

        if (isClientePresente(filtro)) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cliente", filtro.getCliente()));
        }
        if (isBancoPresente(filtro)) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("banco", filtro.getBanco()));
        }

        if (isProdutoPresente(filtro)) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("produto", filtro.getProduto()));
        }

        if (isTabelaPresente(filtro)) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("tabela", filtro.getTabela()));
        }

    }
    return criteria.list();
}

private boolean isProdutoPresente(PropostaFilter filtro) {
    return filtro.getProduto() != null && filtro.getProduto().getCodigo() != null;
}

private boolean isTabelaPresente(PropostaFilter filtro) {
    return filtro.getTabela() != null && filtro.getTabela().getCodigo() != null;
}

private boolean isClientePresente(PropostaFilter filtro) {
    return filtro.getCliente() != null && filtro.getCliente().getCodigo() != null;
}

private boolean isBancoPresente(PropostaFilter filtro) {
    return filtro.getBanco() != null && filtro.getBanco().getCodigo() != null;

}
```

}

PropostaQueries :

```
package com.bss.sistema.genesis.repository.helper.proposta;

import java.util.List;
import com.bss.sistema.genesis.model.Proposta;
import com.bss.sistema.genesis.repository.filter.PropostaFilter;

// O NOME DA INTERFACE SEMPRE NO PLURAL !!!  SE NAO NAO ACHA NA CONTROLLER
public interface PropostasQueries {
public List<Proposta> filtrar (PropostaFilter filtro);
```

}

HTML:

```
<head>
    <title>Pesquisa de propostas</title>
</head>

<body>
<section layout:fragment="conteudo">
    <div class="page-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <h1>Pesquisa de propostas</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="aw-page-header-controls">
                        <a class="btn  btn-default" th:href="@{/propostas/novo}">
                            <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> <span class="hidden-xs  hidden-sm">Nova proposta</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="container-fluid">
            <form  method="GET" th:object="${propostaFilter}">

                <!--  Inicio DIV ADE - CLIENTE -->
                <div class="row">

                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="ade">ADE</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ade" autofocus="autofocus" th:field="*{ade}"/>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="cpf">CPF</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cpf" autofocus="autofocus"  th:field="*{cliente.cpf}"/>
                </div>





                </div>
                        <!--  FIM DIV ADE - CLIENTE -->


                <!--  INICIO DIV BANCO  | PRODUTO | TABELA -->
                <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="banco">Banco</label>
                <select id="banco" class="form-control" th:field=*{banco}>
                <option value="">Todos os Bancos</option>
                <option th:each="banco : ${bancos}" th:value="${banco.codigo}" th:text="${banco.nome}"></option>
                </select>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="produto">Produto</label>
                <select id="produto" class="form-control" th:field=*{produto}>
                <option value="">Todos os Produtos</option>
                <option th:each="produto : ${produtos}"th:value="${produto.codigo}" th:text="${produto.descricao}"></option>
                </select>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label class="control-label" for="produto">Tabela</label>
                <select id="produto" class="form-control" th:field=*{tabela}>
                <option value="">Todos as Tabelas</option>
                <option th:each="tabela : ${tabelas}"th:value="${tabela.codigo}" th:text="${tabela.descricao}"></option>
                </select>
                </div>
                </div>
                <!--  END DIV | PRODUTO | TABELA -->



                <!--  Inicio DIV |PERIODO | VALOR-->
                <div class="row">

                <div class="col-sm-6  form-group">
                <label for="periodo">Período</label>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control  gn-form-control-inline-sm  js-decimal" id="dataIni"/>
                    <label for="periodo" class="gn-form-label-between">até</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control  gn-form-control-inline-sm  js-decimal" id="dataFim"/>
                </div>
            </div>




                <div class="col-sm-6  form-group">
                <label for="valorDe">Valor Total</label>
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control  gn-form-control-inline-sm  js-decimal" id="valorDe" th:field=*{valorDe}>
                    <label for="precoAte" class="gn-form-label-between">até</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control  gn-form-control-inline-sm  js-decimal" id="valorAte" th:field=*{valorAte}>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!--  Inicio DIV |PERIODO | VALOR-->


            <!--  FIM DIV CONTA | DATA NASC | GRUPO-->

        <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary">Pesquisar</button>
    </div>

                </form>




        <!-- INICIO DIV TABLES -->
        <div class="table-responsive gn-tabela-simples" >
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th class="table-propostas-col-ade">ADE</th>
                    <th class="table-propostas-col-cpf">CPF</th>
                    <th class="table-propostas-col-banco">Banco</th>
                    <th class="table-propostas-col-produto">Produto</th>
                    <th class="table-propostas-col-produto">Tabela</th>
                    <th class="table-propostas-col-valorTotal">Valor</th>
                    <th class="table-propostas-col-dataProposta">Data</th>
                    <th class="table-propostas-col-acoes"></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                <tr th:each="proposta : ${propostas}">
                    <td class="text-center" th:text="${proposta.ade}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${proposta.cliente.cpf}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${proposta.banco.nome}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${proposta.produto.descricao}"></td>
                    <td th:text="${proposta.tabela.descricao}"></td>
                    <td th:text="|R$ ${proposta.valorTotal}|"></td>
                    <td th:text="${proposta.dataProposta}">10/05/2018</td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a class="btn  btn-link  btn-xs" title="Editar"> 
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn  btn-link  btn-xs" title="Excluir">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>    
        </table>
        </div>
            <!-- FIM  DIV TABLES -->
    </div>
```

Quem puder ajudar, agradeço.

Comment: Só uma sugestão: em vez de links para o código, é melhor colocar o código na própria pergunta, pois se o pastebin estiver fora (ou a pessoa acessar do trabalho e o proxy da empresa bloquear, por exemplo), será mais difícil ter a informação completa e isso diminui as chances de você obter uma resposta. Veja mais detalhes [nesta resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5489). Se seu código original for muito grande, tente reduzi-lo para um [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa adicionar um `JOIN` entre Proposta e Cliente, desta forma:

```
// veja que adicionei um alias chamado "proposta"
Criteria criteria = manager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Proposta.class, "proposta");
// JOIN entre proposta e cliente, imaginando que na entidade proposta o campo que armazena a entidade cliente chame-se "cliente" mesmo
criteria.createAlias("proposta.cliente", "cliente");
// adiciona a restrição
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cliente.cpf", "123.123.123-12"));
```

No seu código atual, há diversas maneiras de encaixar este código. Se estiver com dúvida quanto a esta organização, sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta. Segue abaixo um exemplo que, embora não faça muito sentido na prática (se você buscar o cliente por ID, não faz sentido buscar ele por CPF), mas dá uma ideia de como pode compor:

```
Criteria criteria = manager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Proposta.class, "proposta");
if (filtro != null) {

    if (isClientePresente(filtro)) {

        criteria.createAlias("proposta.cliente", "cliente");
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cliente", filtro.getCliente)); // na prática, é uma busca por id de cliente

        if (isCpfClientePresente(filtro)) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cliente.cpf", "123.123.123-12"));
        }
    }

    // outros filtros
}
```

Comment: Vou postar a classe Inteira no pasteBin e tu me diz se tem algo errado ? mesmo fazendo seu metodo ele continua igual, quando vou pesquisar no html ele ate aparece que foi digitado na barra de negacao o numero do cpf mas nao traz o especifico , segue os codigo :  Proposta Impl - https://pastebin.com/cbH1bASw  |  PesquisaUsuario.html - https://pastebin.com/9jcPX1f4

Comment: Olá! Não entendi a dúvida. Sua entidade Proposta tem um Cliente? Edite sua pergunta e coloque o código da Proposta e Cliente também

Comment: Beleza Vou enviar  : Proposta :  https://pastebin.com/W105bYB4             Cliente : https://pastebin.com/dMAks1QZ

Comment: Segue as imagens atuais como esta  : Sem pesquisar : https://ibb.co/h02Qdy , Pesquisando o CPF :  https://ibb.co/fOpXQd

Answer (score 0):

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public List<Proposta> filtrar(String CPF) {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Proposta> query = builder.createQuery(Proposta.class);

    Root<Proposta> root = query.from(Proposta.class);

    query.select(root);
    Join<Object, Object> joinCliente = root.join("cliente");//faz o inner join com o cliente e cria um ojeto cliente na query       

    /*
     * adiciona pesquisa da proposta pelo cpf do cliente
     * O where aceita um array de Predicate caso use mais de uma clausula
     */
    query.where(builder.equal(joinCliente.get("cpf"), CPF));


    TypedQuery<Proposta> typedQuery = manager.createQuery(query.distinct(true));


    return typedQuery.getResultList();
}
```